# Magento 2: changing custom theme default layout

Tags: xml, magento, layout, themes, magento2

I have custom theme that inherits no parent theme from Magento.

The default layout appears to be `1column`, and I am able to make modifications to that column in my custom theme's `layout\default.xml` file.

However, I want the default layout for the theme to be `2column-left`, not `1-column`. Looking at Magento's built in themes, it appears this is done by adding the `layout` attribute to the `page` element in `default.xml`.

My custom theme's directory setup is as follows:

```
\Metal
  \bronze
    \Magento_Theme
      \layout
        default.xml
        default_head_blocks.xml
      \page_layout
        1column.xml
        2columns-left.xml
    \media
      ...
    \web
      ...
    composer.json
    registration.php
    theme.xml
```

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLScema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Laout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
      layout="2columns-left">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="header.panel" destination="header.panel.wrapper"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar_main">
            <container name="sidebar_main.newsletter" htmlTag="div" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element name="subscribe" destination="sidebar_main.newsletter"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**1column.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

**2columns-left**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
        <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Any changes I make to `1column.xml` any of its containers referenced in `default.xml` will reflect on the site, but I cannot seem to update the default layout to `2column-left`. None of the defined containers will render on the page, nor will it allow me to move the default newsletter block to the sidebar as a result.

What am I missing? Is `<page layout="..."` not the proper way to do this?

**Aside** *I also posted this question in the Magento community, but given the higher apparent traffic here, I figured I'd post here as well. Is this is a violation of posting etiquette?*

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the page layouts declaration file in your theme, as described here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html#layout-types-page-dec